# Convert JSON objects to array using Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Flow, and I'm using Union to combine two sources, so this union contains JSON documents. Is there a way to convert this JSON document to array of documents?

Union contains:

```
{"key":1,"value":"test8"}
{"key":2,"value":"test6"}
{"key":3,"value":"test3"}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to get like this format:

```
[
 {
   "key": 1,
   "value": "test8"
 },
{
 "key": 2,
 "value": "test6"
},
{
 "key": 3,
 "value": "test3"
}
]
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: How is your sink configured? You can use ADLS or Azure Storage as sinks for your JSON files, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#json-as-sink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Aggregate` transformation and use **collect** expression to combine all the JSON document and pass it to sink with JSON dataset. But this will not output the result exactly what you are looking for and gives **aggregated** **column** name in the output as shown below.

**Aggregate**:

Column1: `collect(@(key=key,value=value))`

[image]

**Data flow Output**:

[image]

As an **alternative**, you can copy the union JSON documents to the storage and use a `copy data` activity to get convert the JSON document to an array of documents.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]